# stack list debug assertion failed c++

Tags: c++, list, stack

When I try to run my code, it show me debug assertion failed .Any one can help me, I am doing stack list,in the header file, I create a struct has three variable, string * s, int numoflength, stackFrame * next

```
     void Stack::push(string& s)
        {

            StackFramePtr temp_ptr;
            temp_ptr=new StackFrame;
            temp_ptr->str=new string[s.size()];
            (temp_ptr->str)[0]=s;
            cout<<temp_ptr->str[0]<<endl;
            temp_ptr->num_char=sizeofstring(s);
            if(empty())
            {
                top=temp_ptr;
                temp_ptr->next=NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                temp_ptr->next=top;
                top=temp_ptr;
            }
        }

this is my code about push I think maybe those errors because of this function.
string Stack::pop()
{
    if(empty())
        exit(1);
    string * name;
    StackFramePtr temp;
    temp=top;
    name=top->str;
    top=top->next;
    delete temp;
    return *name;
}

#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1="to";
    string str2="hi";
    string str3="food";
    string str4="ba";
    string str5="ti";
    string str6="zhilong";
    Stack s;
    s.push(str1);
    s.push(str2);
    s.push(str3);
    s.push(str4);
    s.push(str5);
    s.push(str6);
    cout<<s;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to run this main function it give me debug failure, anyone can help me? thanks very much

```
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    //Default Constructor used to create an empty Stack object.

    ~Stack();
    //Destructor for Stack objects.

    void push(string& str);

    string pop();

    bool empty();
    //Checks to see if the Stack is empty.  Returns true if empty, else returns false.
    //Stack remains unchanged after function call.


    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream & out_stream, Stack & mystack);

    friend istream &operator>>(istream & in_stream, Stack & mystack);

private:
    StackFramePtr top; // Points to the top of the stack;

};
ostream &operator<<(ostream & outs, Stack & sta)
{
    if(sta.empty())
        exit(1);
    else
    {
        StackFramePtr read;
        read=sta.top;
        while(read!=NULL)
        {
            outs<<"string = "<<read->str[0]<<endl;
            outs<<" number of charcter is" <<read->num_char;
            read=read->next;
            outs<<endl<<endl;
        }
    }
    return outs;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Stack class created?

Comment: Yes. I do create a stack class, and pop and push both are public member fuction

Comment: Can you show the stack class?

Comment: class Stack
{
public:
 Stack();
 ~Stack();
 void push(string& str);
 string pop();
 StackFramePtr remove_strings_length(int length);
 bool empty();
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream & out_stream, Stack & mystack);
 friend istream &operator>>(istream & in_stream, Stack & mystack);
private:
 StackFramePtr top; 
  
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `push` you allocate an array of `string`, and assign that to the `str` member of `Stack`.  In `pop` you copy `str` to `name`, then `delete temp` which (I'm assuming) will delete the array that name is now pointing in to.  Lastly you dereference this dangling pointer and access memory that has already been freed.

To fix this, declare `name` as just a `string`, rather than a pointer to string, then set `name=*top->str` or `name=top->str[0]`.

Comment: I use name=top->str[0], and then delete temp,  but it still give me debug assertion failed, it said string subscript out of range.

Comment: The code for `friend ostream &operator<<(ostream & out_stream, Stack & mystack)` is not shown.  The problem could be in there.

Comment: Can you check my ostream, but I feel that no errors in the ostream, maybe because of push, because in the main function, I only use default and push function and cout.

Comment: Does it tell you where the debug assertion failed?  If you run that in the debugger you can look up the call stack to see what part of your code has the fault in it.

Comment: No it does not say where is failure, I am no quite sure how to use debugger, can you tell me how to use that?